# socket.io/1/?t= not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, socket.io

I have a web app that is running on rails 4 at localhost:3000. I am also have angularjs on client side. I have placed scoket.io.js file in my rails app public folder. From my angularjs client code, I run this code

```
 this.connect = function (endpoint) {

        if(!socket) {
            socket = io.connect(endpoint);
            socket.on('connect', connectHandler);
            socket.on('connect_failed', connectFailedHandler);

            socket.on('message', messageHandler);

            socket.on('disconnect', disconnectHandler);
            socket.on('close', disconnectHandler);
            socket.on('nexus_disconnect', this.disconnect);
        } else {
            socket.socket.connect(endpoint);
        }
    };
```

I am getting error as below on my browser console.

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1405687049255 404 (Not Found)
```

Is any server other than rails server needed for socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to set up [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) server.

There are several implementations of Socket.IO server in other languages, but it seems that there is no one written in Ruby.

Comment: I have installed Node.js on my mac. Rails server also running on 3000 port. When I start node.js server my socket.io.js file not found. Because it fetched through node.js server link. How I start its server with no conflict with rails server.

Comment: @Lalit all you need to avoid conflict is make Rails and Node listen different ports

Comment: I am getting this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3002/socket.io/1/?t=1405946169314. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access." when running node.js server on 3002 port and rails server 3000 port.

Comment: @Lalit try to navigate to http://localhost:3002/socket.io/ . What do you see in your browser? If you see something like `{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`, Socket.IO is able to respond, and the error maybe occurs because of Socket.IO internal settings. Otherwise Socket.IO just can't intercept requests.